# How to trigger WordPress theme translations via page slug?

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, translation

I would like to translate some theme strings. I am able to trigger the translations using a URL parameter.

```
add_filter('locale', 'change_locale_param');
function change_locale_param($locale){
    if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
        return sanitize_text_field($_GET['lang']);
    }
    return $locale;
}
```

However, I would like to do this based on if the page is the descendant of a page with the slug `es`.

I tried this way and it changes the "lang" parameter in the `html` tag.

```
add_filter('locale', 'change_locale_slug');
function change_locale_slug($locale){
    $es = get_id_by_slug('es');
    $en = get_id_by_slug('en');
    
    if(is_page('es') || is_child_of($es)){
        return 'es';
    }
    elseif(is_front_page() || is_child_of($en) || !has_post_parent()){
        return 'en';
    }
    return $locale;
}
```

Is there a way to do that? How does the URL parameter trigger the translations and how do I replicate that behavior?

Oddly the translations appear on the page `/es/contacto/` but not on, say, `/es/` or `/es/politica-de-privacidad/`.

Comment: This is not how you translate theme or plugin. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/

Comment: I just want a few lines translated via `_e()` function. I don't want to use a plugin for a few areas and be reliant on a third party plugin. I would like to handle this separately. Is that not possible? If not, I don't understand how it works on `/es/contacto/` and not `/es/politica-de-privacidad/`.